# error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied when using php script for git pull

Tags: php, linux, git, nginx, server

I mad simple php script for git pull

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("cd /var/www/domain.tld/html/test/ && git pull 2>&1");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

named it git.php and gave it 755

the output was

```
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

but when try from the terminal

```
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

i checked the directories ownership , my user is "savvy"

```
drwxrwsr-x  4 savvy savvy     4096 Jul 13 05:40 test
```

and the files inside

```
$ ls -la test/
total 20
drwxrwsr-x 4 savvy savvy 4096 Jul 13 05:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 savvy savvy 4096 Jul 13 05:38 ..
drwxrwsr-x 8 savvy savvy 4096 Jul 13 05:41 .git
-rw-rwSr-- 1 savvy savvy   19 Jul 13 05:39 test.php
```

.git

```
$ ls -la .git/
total 60
drwxrwsr-x 8 savvy savvy 4096 Jul 13 05:41 .
drwxrwsr-x 4 savvy savvy 4096 Jul 13 05:40 ..
drwxrwsr-x 2 savvy savvy 4096 Jul 13 05:39 branches
-rw-rwSr-- 1 savvy savvy  268 Jul 13 05:39 config
-rw-rwSr-- 1 savvy savvy   73 Jul 13 05:39 description
-rw-rwSr-- 1 savvy savvy   97 Jul 13 05:41 FETCH_HEAD
-rw-rwSr-- 1 savvy savvy   23 Jul 13 05:39 HEAD
drwxrwsr-x 2 savvy savvy 4096 Jul 13 05:39 hooks
-rw-rwSr-- 1 savvy savvy  104 Jul 13 05:41 index
drwxrwsr-x 2 savvy savvy 4096 Jul 13 05:39 info
drwxrwsr-x 3 savvy savvy 4096 Jul 13 05:39 logs
drwxrwsr-x 4 savvy savvy 4096 Jul 13 05:39 objects
-rw-rwSr-- 1 savvy savvy   41 Jul 13 05:40 ORIG_HEAD
-rw-rwSr-- 1 savvy savvy  107 Jul 13 05:39 packed-refs
drwxrwsr-x 5 savvy savvy 4096 Jul 13 05:39 refs
```

~/.ssh

```
drwx------ 2 savvy savvy 4096 Jul 13 04:56 .ssh
```

inside

```
$ ls -la .ssh/
total 36
drwx------ 2 savvy savvy 4096 Jul 13 04:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 savvy savvy 4096 Jul 12 08:34 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 savvy savvy  398 Jul 12 05:46 authorized_keys
-rw-rw-r-- 1 savvy savvy   59 Jul 11 10:10 config
-rw------- 1 savvy savvy 1679 Jul 11 07:44 id_rsa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 savvy savvy  398 Jul 12 05:21 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 savvy savvy 1768 Jul 13 05:08 known_hosts
```

Comment: How are you running your php script?  As which user?

Comment: calling it from the url : domain.tld/git.php
and created git.php with savvy user

Comment: The url is served by a webserver, which is running as which user?  You may need to add the webserver's user to your group.

Comment: `$ ps aux|grep nginx|grep -v grep

root     12433  0.0  0.2  85892  1400 ?        Ss   Jul12   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data 12435  0.0  0.3  86188  1620 ?        S    Jul12   0:09 nginx: worker process
www-data 12436  0.0  0.4  86556  2104 ?        S    Jul12   0:01 nginx: worker process
www-data 12437  0.0  0.3  86188  1620 ?        S    Jul12   0:09 nginx: worker process
www-data 12438  0.0  0.3  86532  1868 ?        S    Jul12   0:08 nginx: worker process`

Comment: i add www-data user to savvy group and same result

Comment: Could you try becoming the www-data user and then performing the git pull.  You may find that you are missing permissions on a directory a level above.

Comment: Thanks xxfelixx that works , i will post what i did in order solve this problem

Comment: Great!  Nice work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem by the following

**Step #1**: copy /home/savvy/.ssh to /var/www/

```
# cp -R /home/savvy/.ssh /var/www/
```

**Step #2**: gave the /var/www directory to www-data user

```
# chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
```

**Step #3**: login as www-data user

```
$ su
Password: 
# su -s /bin/bash www-data
```

**Step #4**: clone the repo into my directory /var/www/domain.tld/html/test/

**Step #5**: call the git.php file i made already domain.tld/git.php

Result

```
From bitbucket.org:repo/test
8e9f67c..185cd9e  master     -> origin/master
Updating 8e9f67c..185cd9e
Fast-forward
test.php | 1 +
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Comment: In my setup I have a git repo with group write access, and the solution was to add www-data to that group: ``sudo gpasswd -a www-data mygitgroup``. After restarting ``apache2`` in ``systemctl`` calling the PHP script would now successfully fetch from Git.